# Is there a way to get outlook push notification, only when a specific field of calendar item is updated?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I followed the [Outlook push notification documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/notify-rest-operations) to subscribe for calendar notifications. And I am able to receive push notification whenever calendar item is changed or deleted. Now I want to receive push notification only when specific properties`(example: To, Start time and End time properties)` of calendar item are updated or calendar item itself is deleted.

Is there any API available to implement above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported, the hooks are scoped at the object level (`event`, `user`, etc). You cannot subscribe to an individual property.